# cannot get php global variables using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
if(!isset($_GET['t'])){$table = 'notes';}
else{$table = $_GET['t'];}

$cats = $table . '_cats';

include 'test.php';
```

**test.php**

```
test(); // works fine

if(isset($_POST['fn'])){
    $_POST['fn']();
}

function test(){
    global $cats, $table;
    echo $cats;
    echo $table;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
    $.post('test.php', {fn: 'test'}, function(data){
        console.log(data); // empty
    });
});
```

I'm expecting`$cats` and `$table` written in console

Any help?

Comment: are you confirmed to received `test` in `$_POST['fn']` ? please check first

Comment: @prasanth - yes because `echo 'lorem'` inside fn test - works

Comment: What is the file name where you written `include 'test.php';` ?

Comment: try `echo "$cats , $table"; exit;`

Comment: @RishiRaut - `a_notes.php`

Answer (score 2):

As your first file name is `a_notes.php` then call `a_notes.php` from ajax. You are defining `$cats, $table` in `a_notes.php` not in `test.php`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
    $.post('a_notes.php', {fn: 'test'}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },'json');// set dataType as json
});
```

Also in `test.php`, As you are calling a function `test()` then echo returned value of function.

```
echo test();

if(isset($_POST['fn'])){
    $_POST['fn']();
}

function test(){
    global $cats, $table;
    return json_encode(["cats"=>$cats,"table"=>$table]);
}
```

Comment: but `test.php` is included in `a_notes.php`. I tried to define `cats` and `table` inside `test.php` - the same result. `a_notes.php` is the main file.

Comment: @qadenza: Call `$.post('a_notes.php'`